# Check if the method in a delegate is equal to one of my class functions (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates, compare

I've recently found out about delegates in VB.NET so I'm trying to do some tests to familiarise myself with how they work. First I was able to get create one and point it to a function that simply prints to the screen like so:

```
Public Delegate Function ByteDelegate() As Byte

Sub Main()
    Dim testDelegate As ByteDelegate = AddressOf PrintHello
    otherDelegate()
End Sub

Public Function PrintHello()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!")
        Return &H0
End Function
```

Next I wanted to see if I could check if a one of these delegates does in fact point to the PrintHello() function I have. I've tried doing the following:

```
If test.operate.Method = otherDelegate.Method

If test.operate.Method.Name.CompareTo(otherDelegate.Method.Name)
```

But neither of them seem to provide valid results, I've searched around online and haven't found anything of help so far and I'm struggling to understand how I should be going about this so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
After having some feedback I've updated my code to use Actions or Funcs, both of which I get the same behaviour. Since my functions need return types I have stuck to using Func(Of Byte) since actions still seem to return false when compared and from what I've been told I should only be using them for Subs.

I have a structure called INSTRUCTION which holds an action and a string like so:

```
Private Structure INSTRUCTION
    Public operate As Func(Of Byte)
    Public text As String
    
    Public Sub New(_operate As Func(Of Byte), _text As String)
        operate = _operate
        text = _text
    End Sub
End Structure
```

I then make a type of INSTRUCTION which addresses my PrintHello function, as well as making another action with the same function to compare:

```
Dim test As New INSTRUCTION(AddressOf PrintHello, "Other text.")
Dim otherFunction As Func(Of Byte) = AddressOf PrintHello
```

When I try to compare these actions with

```
otherFunction.Equals(test.operate)
```

it just returns false.

I don't understand what could be going on at all, I don't think anything has ever stumped me this much.

Comment: Firstly, while it doesn't hurt to learn how, you should rarely need to declare your own delegate type. There are various places throughout the Framework that you will need to use specific delegates and, otherwise, you should just use an `Action` to invoke a `Sub` and a `Func` to invoke a `Function`. Both support up to 16 parameters and a `Func` can also return any type.

Comment: When you do these tests, set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` On. Or, better, keep them `On` all the time. Or - better - forever.

Comment: As for your question, I would suggest that there are far more important things to worry about. In my nearly 20 years of .NET development, I have never once needed to determine whether a delegate refers to a specific method. I can't really think of a situation where you would care. The whole point of a delegate is that you can invoke it anywhere without caring what method of what type it refers to.

Comment: In reference to what @Jimi said, `Option Explicit` is `On` by default and there is literally never a reason to turn it `Off`. `Option Strict` is `Off` by default and you should have it `On` pretty much all the time. That means turning it `On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so that it is `On` by default for all future projects. On the rare occasions that you need to use late binding, you can turn `Option Strict Off` at the file level and use partial classes to ensure that only the code that specifically needs it is in those files.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, the experiments were based on what I needed to do for my little project. I found delegates after researching if there was a way to make function pointers in VB. The reason I'm trying to check it in delegates is because I'm trying to map an opcode table made up of a structure I've made that contains two delegates, consider them 'addressingMode' and 'opcode'. Because for the opcodes I've got around 50 of them, with around 10 addressing modes, and obviously there's a lot of possibilities so I guessed if I could check that way it might make things easier?

Comment: I wonder if for something like this, digging into the expression machinery would be more fruitful?  In that case, instead of taking a `Func` or `Action` as an input, you would take an `Expression(Of Func(Of ...))` or `Expression(Of Action(Of ...))` as an input.  Ultimately, you would end up getting to the underlying function instead of the wrapper delegate this way.

Comment: Okay, I've replaced the delegates in my structure with Func(Of Byte) and it still seems to work when I call it so that's great. I'm still trying to compare them with If test.operate = otherFunction where test is just a new type of my instruction structure. I also tried using If test.operate.Method = otherFunction.Method but that's not working either, they never produce true. How would I compare these Func(Of Byte) variables now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I've finally figured it out, after changing where I declared my own delegate types to just use Func(Of Byte) in order to compare two of them I also needed to explicitly state the 'As Byte' in the function like so:

```
Public Function PrintHello() As Byte
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!")
    Return &HFF
End Function
```

Whereas before I just had it like this:

```
Public Function PrintHello()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!")
    Return &HFF
End Function
```

So it turns out it was something really simple in the end, thanks for showing me where to use Action and Func though it'll be great for future reference.

Comment: You should have `Option Strict On` and then you would be forced to do that. Turn it `On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it will be `On` by default for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a bit of testing and it appears that the `Equals` method of a delegate will tell you whether it refers to the same method as another delegate, e.g.

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim d1 As New Action(AddressOf Method1)
        Dim d2 As New Action(AddressOf Method2)

        Dim dX As New Action(AddressOf Method1)

        If dX.Equals(d1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("dX.Equals(d1)")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not dX.Equals(d1)")
        End If

        If dX.Equals(d2) Then
            Console.WriteLine("dX.Equals(d2)")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not dX.Equals(d2)")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that the delegates must be the same type for this to work. Two delegates of two different types with the same signature cannot be equal, even if they refer to the same method.

Comment: Okay, I tried doing this and I got the same behaviour as before. I've got a structure called INSTRUCTION that has an action in it which is getting compared to another which is just stored as a normal variable. I overrode the New sub in the structure so I could assign actions and strings to each instruction directly instead of doing it in a few lines. I make one of my instructions like this: Dim test As New INSTRUCTION(New Action(AddressOf PrintHello), "Other text."). I then do this: Dim otherFunction As New Action(AddressOf PrintHello). otherFunction.Equals(test.operate) seems to return false.

Comment: Does the code above work for you as I described? Can you update your question with the exact current code you're using?

Comment: Okay just an update,  if I change the functions to subs it works, but I need them to have return types so I'm using functions that return a byte. I've detailed it above since when comparing Func(Of Byte) I always get false, and I also get false when they are two actions but I'm assuming that's because I shouldn't use actions with functions that return a value. Anyhow I've detailed it all above and updated the question too. Thanks.